# Can't cancel alarm with AlarmManager.cancel() on 24 API

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

Have 2 methods:

1. `addAlarm()`

```
val myIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
if (SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    myIntent.action = "ADD_ALARM"
} else {
    myIntent.putExtra("alarm", alarm)
}
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
else
    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
/*
    if I try to cancel alarm after creating like this:

    val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)

    it would work and alarm would be canceled. Seems like problem is 
    in pendingIntent.
*/
```

2. `deleteAlarm()`

```
val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
var myIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
//with flag FLAG_NO_CREATE return null
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)
```

Everything works great on api 23, but on api 24 alarm do not canceling. Is it problem with `intent.action`? What did i miss?

Comment: Are you seeing any exceptions thrown in the logs?

Comment: No, there are no any exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it with adding `intent.action` like this:

```
val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
var myIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
if (SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    myIntent.action = "ADD_ALARM"
}
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)
```